# Добавление в поле поиска через JavaScript при нажатии на блок

Tags: javascript, html

На странице есть много блоков одного размера, надо сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на блок, его название добавлялось в поле поиска ***`input`***. Так как новичок, решил сделать из них чекбоксы (конечно, если можно сделать по другому, посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как именно). Нашел на просторах интернета некоторую информацию и сделал маленький пример

```js
'use strict';
var items = document.querySelectorAll('[class="help"]');
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var links = Array.from(items).forEach(item => {
    if ($('input').is(':checked')) {
      output.innerHTML += `$ {
      item.name
    }
    </br>`;
    } else {
      output.innerHTML += ``;
    }
  }

);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="scales" class="help" name="scales" checked>
<label for="scales">Scales</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="horns" class="help" name="horns">
<label for="horns">Horns</label></br>
<div id='output'></div>
```

но работает он криво. Может кто занимался похожим и может помочь?

Comment: Что за гибрид из `js` и `jq` непонятный

Comment: не сильно еще разбираюсь в js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы про это?

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.help')]
    .forEach(checkbox => checkbox.onchange = update)

update()

function update() {
  document.getElementById('output').value = 
    [...document.querySelectorAll('input:checked + label')]
        .map(label => label.textContent).join(' ');
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="scales" class="help" checked>
<label for="scales">Scales</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="horns" class="help">
<label for="horns">Horns</label><br>
<input id='output'>
```

Comment: да, спасибо огромное!)

Comment: @dduckker отлично, пожалуйста